# what is the difference between has parentheses at the end of self-invoked function or has not in the javascript?

Tags: javascript

what is the difference between these two case of usage self-invoke function exactly?please answer this question is similar but not duplicated!

---

NO.1:

```js
(function () 
{
  console.log('Test');
}()
);
```

NO.2:

```js
(function () 
{
    console.log('Test');
}
);
```

Comment: The first one is a self-invoked function. The parentheses are what invokes it. The second one is just a function expression - it's not invoked, because there are no parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is self-invoked and run automaticly. and running the code ; and cant assinging that in the variable like these:

```
var f1 =(function () 
{
  console.log('Test');
}()
);
```

The second one is a declaration of a function and should assing to a variable like this:

```
var f2 =(function () 
{
    console.log('Test');
}
);

f2();
```

Comment: In the first case, you can't assign *the function* to a variable, but you *can* assign its return value, if it returns anything.

Comment: @deceze and in the second case the outer brackets are superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is Immediately Invoked Function Expression because we are invoking it right away after getting defined or declared.

The second one is the function Expression we are defining but not invoking it.

Comment: The second one is a function *expression*, it's not a declaration. Declarations are statements.

Comment: I have not noticed that thanks for notifying written in the flow.